# Use div in multiple locations

Tags: html, css

I want to know if you can use one div and have it pop on with CSS in other places to save space and make things more organized. I have a set of code that uses the same lines for a lot of it, it's buttons and what have you in a pop up. So I want to sit the div in a nice spot and use CSS to have it pop up under different pop ups

```
<div class = "example">
<ul class = "list">
<li>example</li>
<select name = "example">
<option value = "0">0</option>
</select></li>
<input ...example text...>
</ul>
</div>
```

So that sits inside another div that is an image and some text that CSS has pop up when a link is clicked, it's just a list of things to pick for a e-commerce page, I have to rewrite it each for each new item, the CSS I have for it just sets the pop up display and I have jquery for the pop up action. Instead of having that said code above being rewritten each time I want it once and use CSS or java to have it pop up with all of the pop ups

Comment: You can use JS to move the position of it inside of a certain div, or you can used position fixed on the item. Without a code example it's hard to know what you mean.

Comment: Yes you can, just use `position: absolute;` on the div that needs to pop.

Comment: To use it in different pop ups you'll need to use javascript. document.getElementById('another-popup').appendChild(document.getElementById('resuable-div'))

Answer (score 0):

You could bootstrap and a `modal` for popups since you will have an easier time with them and you can do all sorts of things with modals.

And Bootstrap is **INCREDIBLY** easy to use

[Bootstrap Modal example](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp/)

```
 <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

 <!-- Modal -->
      <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
     </div>
```

This is the example from [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) - I know it seems like a lot, but Bootstrap will change your web design world :)

Answer (score 0):

save the code you wrote (ex: as example.php).

then you can use it with other pages using an include/require:

for example: (example2.php)

```
include 'example.php';

or

require 'example.php';
```

You can use this syntax anytime and anywhere within the php file.

Comment: but you have to call the page from a server for this to work. XAMPP or similar work as a local solution, but just opening the file in a browser won't work.

Comment: I agree. It wasn't mentioned, however, that he needed the file to open without a server. That mentioned, it could still be a solution to the issue.